# Relative Height of UL LI List

Tags: html, css, html-lists, accordion

I have Ul LI list

My list is dynamic and I can't set fixed height on child.

I need control height of my Li [child of ul] by percent to create accordion or some thing like that.

```css
ul {
    position:reletive
}
li 

{
    display:block;
    margin:20px;
    position:reletive;
    overflow:hidden
}
```

```html
<ul style="">
    <li style="height:50%">
        asdasdasd <br>
        asdasdasd <br>
        asdasdasd <br>
        asdasdasd <br>
        asdasdasd <br>
        asdasdasd <br>
        asdasdasd <br>
        asdasdasd <br>
        asdasdasd <br>
    </li>
      <li style="">
        bcvbcvbcv
    </li>
      <li style="">
        asdasdasd
    </li>
      <li style="">
        asdasdasd
    </li>
    
</ul>
```

Why doesn't percent height work on Dynamic Heights..

Comment: Because it would create a circular dependency. The content height would depend on the container height, and the container height would depend on the content height.

Comment: I don't know if reletive can work. I think it was relative.

Answer (score 0):

because the height of li will be in your case 50% of what?
why do you set the position of ul to relative?

what you need is to set a default height for li, an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oussamaelgoumri/e3odjLcu/)

```
ul {

}

li {
    margin:20px;
    position:reletive;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 30px;
}
```

in case you need something like accordion, you can give your li  a default height, then adjust it to `height: auto` when some event occur, like click on javascript, or just hover on css:

```
li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: auto;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oussamaelgoumri/LkL2h456/) for the accordion like example

Comment: Dear "Oussama ELGOUMRI"
we dont have height of this li also parent height.. ; i want to have animation from 0 percent to 100 percent.

Comment: @user1158113 do you want to create something like accordion ??